# Android Camera2 Preview Image Decoding fails on car head unit

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I am pretty new to Camera2 API and currenty trying to implement a camera preview into my own car application on an Android head unit (Model YT9213AJ). The preview should show the image of the reverse camera.

I've tested the following code on a Samsung Tablet (SM-P610) and it shows the camera preview images as expected, from both, rear and front camera.

```
    private void bindPreview(@NonNull ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider) {

            CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
                .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT)
                .build();

            CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) context.getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE);
            Size previewSize = getPreviewSize(manager.getCameraCharacteristics("1"));

            Preview preview = new Preview.Builder()
                .setTargetResolution(previewSize)
                .setDefaultResolution(previewSize)
                .setMaxResolution(previewSize)
                .setTargetRotation(Surface.ROTATION_270)
                .build();

            preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.getSurfaceProvider());

            Camera camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner)this, cameraSelector, preview);
    }
```

With this function to get the preview size:

```
    Size getPreviewSize(CameraCharacteristics characteristics) {
        StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
        Size[] previewSizes = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class);
        return previewSizes[0]; // for the camera just one resolution is given, so this should be sufficient
    }
```

This is what the image looks like, if I run it on the car head unit:

[Example image preview from car head unit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Nlta.jpg)
(Sorry, can't embed images into post yet)

I've also run the App "Camera2 API probe", please find the results [here on AirBeat](http://airbeat.com/cam2/620a7c278ff64d2399efbe0e). The camera with ID 5 seems to be an placeholder, I assume that the other two cameras (ID 0 and ID 1) are the representations of the two hardware inputs into the head unit.

Do you have any clue how I can correctly decode the image for this camera model? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You could try seeing if not rotating the output helps - the size listed by the camera is already portrait aspect ratio.

In general, though, it looks like whoever made this head unit didn't take a lot of care in making sure the camera output works with the display side, I'm guessing.  So it may not be possible to get it to work with the CameraX PreviewView as-is. The PreviewView tries to select the best kind of output View for the API level that the device is, but it may be picking a path the manufacturer didn't actually test with. There's no built-in way to have it select the other option (SurfaceView or TextureView are the choices), so you'd have to modify PreviewView code or build your own Preview surface provider.

There's also no guarantee that'll help, depending on exactly how badly this device implements things.